# How do I include all documents in the Sphinx globaltoc sidebar?

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, tableofcontents, toctree

I would like every single document in the entire TOC to be included in the globaltoc sidebar. How do I achieve this?

In theme files, there are calls to `{{ toctree() }}`, but I don't know what `toctree()` refers to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [sphinxcontrib-fulltoc](http://sphinxcontrib-fulltoc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) sphinx extension to include a complete TOC in the side bar.